# COnfiguring PVM in Linux Mint 15

Tags: c, linux, makefile, mpi, pvm

While configuring PVM on Linux Mint; These lines was copy into .profile, bash.bashrc, csh.cshrc, profile

```
PVM_ROOT=/home/pvm3
PVM_ARCH="/home/pvm3/lib/pvmgetarch"
PVM_RSH=/etc/ssh
PVM_TMP=/tmp

#putting pvm bin to the path
PATH=$PVM_ROOT/bin:$PATH
#make these variables available for use in the shell
export PVM_ROOT PVM_ARCH PVM_RSH PVM_TMP
```

After these settings I proceeded to make file
when I type make

```
/home/pvm3 $ make
```

The following error is showing:

```
./lib/aimk -here -f ./conf/`./lib/pvmtmparch`.def -f ./Makefile.aimk default
grep: /home/pvm3/conf//home/pvm3/lib/pvmgetarch.def: No such file or directory
making in . for /home/pvm3/lib/pvmgetarch
./lib/aimk: 100: exec: PVM_ARCH=/home/pvm3/lib/pvmgetarch: not found
make: *** [default] Error 127
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what I have done wrongly for having this error and assist for any possible way to correct it.

Comment: I'm sorry to not have more constructive answers for you,but you might want to look at mpi -- pvm has not been updated for many years.

Comment: @Rob Latham: I have checked MPI3, before PVM. It is from the document I was directed to use PVM for the creation of Virtual machine that will allow MPI world of processes to stay. So, I want to create that virtual machine before using MPI. From what i have read so far, I think MPI is build on PVM architecture.

Comment: PVM and MPI are totally different pieces of software.  MPI builds upon PVM's ideas and concepts.